# Suppose I am using KM curve to estimate S(t) parametrically (say assuming it follows lognormal)

Tags: survival, lognormal-distribution, kaplan-meier

Suppose I am using KM curve to estimate S(t) parametrically (say assuming it follows lognormal). Now this t is in (say) months, and I want to get estimates of the lognormal curve where t is in weeks, how would I go about it, I am of the belief that the curve will be the same as what we would obtain if we put 0.25*t in place of t in the survival function S(t). Any thoughts, pls share!

Answer (score 1):

The curve will be similar, but most months are a bit longer than 4 weeks, so a fit to t[weeks] will not be exactly the same as 0.25*t[months].

Comment: okay thanks! will a fit to t[weeks] be same as (7/30.44)*t[months].. does this seem better?

Comment: In this leap year of 2024, all months are longer than 4 weeks.